# SQL Script to insert a object

Tags: sql

I am working on a homework assignment and this is the question:

```
    Write a script that attempts to insert a new division named “Guitars” into the Division table. If the
    insert is successful, the script should display this message:
    SUCCESS: Record was inserted.

If the update is unsuccessful, the script should display a message something like this:
    FAILURE: Record was not inserted.
    Error 2627: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
    'UQ__Division__5A98D48EAD30FDC4'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
    'dbo.Division'. The duplicate key value is (Guitars).
```

I honestly have no Idea where to start, just looking for some help. If you are going to give the full answer please explain a little if you can so I can actually learn. Thanks

Comment: Would be nice if you show yours efforts and more details about table columns, it is difficult to help with the provided information

Comment: Learn sql from W3schools like dml, ddl.